# Read from multiple topics and write to single topic - Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

How to read from multiple topics using spark `readStream()` which having different schemas, and `writeStream()` to a single topic  using Spark `StructedSchema`.

Note: Each input topic having different schema

Comment: Probably you will have to join your streaming datasets into your desired dataset and then do `writeStream`. An important remark is joining of streaming datasets were introduced in Spark 2.3.

Comment: if you are using scala you could take a functional approach to this.  case class SchemaA extends MySchema, case class SchemaB extends MySchema.. then after readStream  `Try` to map the input to each of these classes using pattern matching

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik, just want to append processed result in  a single stream, how to perform join with that?

Comment: what is message type avro ?

Comment: next time pls ask question in detail with examples and details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to read from multiple topics using spark readStream() which having
>   different schemas, and writeStream() to a single topic using Spark
>   StructedSchema ?

I am giving general idea or pointers here .... may suite your case.

I assume you are using avro messages,  there are 2 topics one for message and another one is for schema I am referring to as message topic and schema topic.

Now, prepare a generic row wrapper schema say `avro_yourrow_wrapper.avsc` which holds different schema messages(since you told each message has different schema).

For example: modify this sample as per your requirements.

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "generic_schema",
  "namespace" : "yournamespace",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "messagenameOrTableNames",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "schema",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {
    "name" : "payload",
    "type" : "bytes"
  } ]
}
```

save it to file called avro_yourrow_wrapper.avsc since its static...

```
// Read the wrapper schema in your consumer.
    val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("avro_yourrow_wrapper.avsc")
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
    val wrapperSchema = try source.mkString finally source.close()
```

from spark structured stream you will get a dataframe. read the wrapper schema based on type of message apply record specific schema by reading schema topic and message topic read the avro message.

Now using twitter bijection api (with `GenericRecord`) you can decode the message in to readable format.

sample pseudo code snippet :

```
import com.twitter.bijection.Injection
        import com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs
        import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
        val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(localschema.get( recordlevelschema).get)
        val recordInjection: Injection[GenericRecord, Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)
        val record: GenericRecord = recordInjection.invert(bytes).get
        log.info("record.getSchema" +record.getSchema)
        record.getSchema.getFields.toArray().foreach(x =>log.info(x.toString))
```

And then you can write in to separate topic as you wish.